# QiitaAPIのOAuthについて

Tags: swift, api, oauth

codeをもらうところまでは正常に動いておりますが、AccessTokenをもらうPOSTを実行すると

```
SUCCESS: {
    error = "Internal Server Error";
    status = 500;
}
```

が帰ってきてAccessTokenをもらうことが出来ません。
AccessTokenを返してもらうにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

以下ソースコードです

```
class AuthViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    private var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://qiita.com/api/v2/oauth/authorize?client_id=\(AppUser.clientID)&scope=read_qiita+write_qiita")
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.webView.load(urlRequest)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view = self.webView
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.request.url?.scheme == "tomoki-qiita-client" {
            if navigationAction.request.url?.host == "oauth" && navigationAction.request.url?.lastPathComponent == "qiita" {
                let code = getQueryStringParameter(url: (navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString)!, param: "code")
                getAccessToken(code: code)
            }
        }
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
    }

    private func getQueryStringParameter(url: String, param: String) -> String? {
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: url) else { return nil }
        return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
    }

    private func getAccessToken(code: String!) {
        let url = "https://qiita.com/api/v2/access_tokens"
        guard let code = code else { return }

        // 受信可能なレスポンスデータのメディアタイプを指定
        let headers = [
            "ACCEPT": "application/json"
        ]

        // 認証に必要な値を設定
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "client_id": AppUser.clientID,
            "client_secret": AppUser.clientSecret,
            "code": code
        ]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON{ response in
            print(parameters)
            print(url)
            print(headers)
            print(response)
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)
//                let json = JSON(response.result.value)
//
//                // アクセストークンを取得
//                let accessToken = json["access_token"].string
//                UserDefaults.standard.set(accessToken!, forKey: ACCESS_TOKEN)
//                completion()
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

QiitaAPIのドキュメントはこちらです
https://qiita.com/api/v2/docs#%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC%E8%AA%8D%E5%8F%AF

Comment: `Internal Server Error` とのことで、Qiita内部の問題の可能性があります。Qiitaサポート（ [リクエストを送信 – Qiita:Support](https://support.qiita.com/hc/ja/requests/new) ）に相談してみると良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

省略可能なのかも知れませんが、`parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default`の様に、`encoding`指定が必要では無いでしょうか？

また、JSON形式のテキストを`POST`するので、`httpHeader`は、

```
    let headers = [
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "ACCEPT": "application/json"
    ]
```

と、送信形式が`JSON`であることを明示しなければいけないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。header部分に追記しエンコードをしてすることでTokenが帰ってきました。本当にありがとうございます

Comment: お役に立てて良かったです。このサイトでは、出来ましたやありがとうございますのコメントはあまり良いものとされず、回答の横のプラス投票や、質問を満足出来た回答にチェックマークを付けて、質問が解決した事を明確にすることを期待されていますので、ご協力下さいますでしょうか？

Comment: チェックマークを付けさせていただきました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。チェックが付くと、満足する回答が付いた質問になり、同じ疑問を持った人が見つけやすくなるので、このサイトを訪れた人のためになるので、みんなに嬉しい事です。